# Android AsyncTask with ListView containing Button onClickListener

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-asynctask, android-listview

I have a listview which is filled with data form sqlitedatabase. A list-view element contains a TextView a Button and a Checkbox. Clicking on the Button shows a timepicker dialog. Accepting a time from the timepickerdialog starts an AsyncTask. There is always a new AsyncTask created when I click on the button.

Now when I click on the seventh List-Item, the first list item is updated. There might be an error with the threads.

the activity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String TAG = "SettingsActivity";
    private ReminderBusAdapter busAdapter;
    private List<Reminder> reminderGoalsList;
    private static final int TIME_PICKER_DIALOG = 1;
    private static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";
    private Calendar mCalendar;

    // view elements
    TextView tvStatus;
    ListView listViewReminder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);

        // fetch required data reminder
        busAdapter = new ReminderBusAdapter(this);
        loadSettingsData();

        // generate view
        displayView();

        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    private void loadSettingsData() 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "loadSettingsData");
        reminderGoalsList = new ArrayList<Reminder>();
        reminderGoalsList = busAdapter.receiveReminders();

        Iterator<Reminder> iter = reminderGoalsList.iterator();
        Log.i(TAG, "iterate through all Reminders fetched from db");

        int cnt = 0;
        while (iter.hasNext()) 
        {
            cnt++;
            Log.i(TAG, cnt + "] " + iter.next().toString());
        }
    }

    private void displayView() 
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "displayView");
        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingsTextView);
        listViewReminder = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsListView);
        listViewReminder.setAdapter(new SettingsAdapter(this,
                            R.layout.settings_reminder_listview, reminderGoalsList));
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle b) 
    {
        switch (id) 
        {
            case TIME_PICKER_DIALOG:
                return showTimePicker(b);
        }
        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }

    private Dialog showTimePicker(final Bundle b) 
    {
        TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, 0,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) 
                            {
                                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                                Reminder rem = (Reminder) b.get("reminder");
                                Log.i(TAG, rem.toString() + " got from adapter");

                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
                                String dateForTimeButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

                                rem.setTime(dateForTimeButton);

                                new UpdateTimerByBtn().execute(new String[] 
                                                        {
                                                            rem.getTime(),
                                                            new String(Integer.toString(rem.getId())) 
                                                        });
                            }
                        }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                        mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
        return timePicker;
    }

    class UpdateTimerByBtn extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting AsyncTask " + "UpdateTimerByBtn new time="
                                             + params[0] + " from id= " + params[1]);

            busAdapter.updateReminder(params[0], Integer.parseInt(params[1])); 
            return "finish";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            loadSettingsData();
            displayView();
        }
    }
}

public class SettingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Reminder> 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "SettingsAdapter";
    private static final int TIME_PICKER_DIALOG = 1;
    private List<Reminder> arrayListReminders;
    private int layout;
    private Activity activity;

    public SettingsAdapter(Activity activity, int layout, List<Reminder> objects) 
    {
        super(activity, layout, objects);

        this.arrayListReminders = objects;
        this.layout = layout;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    static class ViewHolder 
    {
        private TextView listReminderTextView;
        private Button listReminderTimeButton;
        private CheckBox listReminderCheckBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, android.view.ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        final Reminder rem = arrayListReminders.get(position);
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (view == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        }

        if (view != null) 
        {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.listReminderTextView = (TextView) view.
                                        findViewById(R.id.list_reminder_day_textview);

            viewHolder.listReminderTimeButton = (Button) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.settings_reminder_list_time_button);

            viewHolder.listReminderCheckBox = (CheckBox) view
                                .findViewById(R.id.settings_reminder_list_checkbox);

            switch (rem.getId()) 
            {
                case 1:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.Mo);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.Di);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.Mi);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.Do);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.Fr);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.Sa);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    viewHolder.listReminderTextView.setText(R.string.So);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            viewHolder.listReminderTimeButton.setText(rem.getTime() + " " + "Uhr");

            viewHolder.listReminderTimeButton
                      .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) 
                            {
                                Log.i(TAG, "clicked " + rem.toString());

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putSerializable("reminder", rem);

                                ((SettingsActivity) activity).showDialog(TIME_PICKER_DIALOG, bundle);
                            }
                        });

            viewHolder.listReminderCheckBox.setChecked(rem.isEnabled() ? true : false);
        }
        return view;
    };
}
```

---

Thanks for your help - I changed the getView Method and started debugging everything.

I think the problem is where the TimePicker Dialog is created in the Activity.

```
private Dialog showTimePicker(final Bundle b) 
{
    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, 0,
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,int minute) 
                            {
                                mCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                                mCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

                                Reminder rem = (Reminder) b.get("reminder");
                                Log.i(TAG, rem.toString() + " got from adapter");

                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(TIME_FORMAT);
                                String dateForTimeButton = dateFormat.format(mCalendar.getTime());

                                rem.setTime(dateForTimeButton);
                                Log.i(TAG, rem.toString());
                                new UpdateTimerByBtn().execute(new String[] {
                                            rem.getTime(),
                                            new String(Integer.toString(rem.getId())) 
                                        });
                            }
                        }, mCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
                        , mCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
    return timePicker;
}
```

I get the required object from the Bundle. This Bunlde is final and never changes when I transfer a new Bundle from the adapter to the activity. When I click on another Button the same Dialog is shown (with the same value) and the OnTimeSetListener is executed with that final bundle. Is there a way to handle dialiogs form adapters? Should I create one Dialog for each row in the ViewHolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like something is wrong with your getView method in the SettingsAdapter class. First of all, you're using the ViewHolder pattern wrong. The point of the ViewHolder pattern is to avoid calling findViewById every time you used a recycled view.

When convertView is null, you need to instantiate a new view, which is what you're doing. The problem is that, in this case, you aren't giving its subview's any value... you are simply returning the view.

A typical getView using the ViewHolder pattern looks something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView,
    android.view.ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = convertView;
  ViewHolder viewHolder;

  if(view == null) {
    view = layoutInflater.inflate ... // instantiate new view here

    // note that i'm instantiating my View holder when view == null,
    // where you are instantiating it when view != null...
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.subview1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subview1);
    ...
    viewHolder.subviewN = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.subviewN);
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
  }

  viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();

  // view and viewHolder are now appropriately set, so do with them what you must

  viewHolder.subview1.setText("blah blah");
  ...

  return view;
}
```

As I said before, you are assigning values to the view's TextView, Button, and CheckBox only if convertView is not null... in other words, when you create a new View, you just return it as is. Maybe that would be a good place to start debugging.